# C++ Win32 Getting the integer value from a text field

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been writing a simple Stock Market program to help me learn Win32 programming, but I am struggling to learn how to retrieve integers from an edit control. I've learned how to retrieve strings from an edit control using GetWindowText. According to the MSDN documentation I need to use the GetDlgItemInt function.

The code below I have the user select a company(which I got working for strings) to show company stock information. I have another edit control to have the user type in the amount of shares they'd want to purchase. I want to take this value to calculate the cost of shares and display the result to the user.

```
HWND hEditSearchCompanies;
HWND mainWindow; //Parent Window


RECT rect;


BOOL fRelative;
BOOL fError;

rect.left = 200;
rect.right = 600;
rect.top = 50;
rect.bottom = 400;
case WM_COMMAND:
{

      case IDC_CALCULATETYPESHARES:
      {
          int sharesInputed = GetDlgItemInt(hEditSearchCompanies, IDC_EDITTYPESHARES, &fError, fRelative);
     
          swprintf_s(SharesInputedBuffer, 20, L"%d", sharesInputed);
          InvalidateRect(mainWindow, &rect, FALSE); 
      }
      break;

      case IDC_COMPANYINFOBUTTON:
            {
                int len = GetWindowTextLength(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_COMPANYCODEDIT));
                if (len > 0)
                {
                    wchar_t wcEditBuffer[256];

                    GetWindowTextW(hEditSearchCompanies, wcEditBuffer, len + 1);
                    Company SearchForCompany = SearchStrings(hwnd, wcEditBuffer);

                    PrintCompanySearchResults(ChildHDC, SearchForCompany, inputRect);
                }
            }
}
break;

case WM_PAINT:
{
    TextOutW(ChildHDC, x, y, sharesInputedBuffer, wcslen(sharesInputedBuffer));

}
```

I then want to use the sharesInputed value to display the numbers like so:

```
int purchaseCost = sharesInputed * company.PricePerShare;
...//Display result to the user
```

However sharesInputed is always returning zero. I'll put in, say 50 shares. If a company's price per share cost is $63.13, my program should be printing $3,156.50, but sharesInputed is always equal to zero whenever I hit my button to calculate the cost.

MSDN documentation doesn't really have any troubleshooting tips for GetDlgItemInt, and have debugged my program numerous times, but still get 0. Looked around and found a few reasons for this but none have worked for me.

I am not getting any error messages or warnings based on my sharesInputted value.

Hopefully I provided enough code. My control ids match for the windows and buttons.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you putting the line of code `int purchaseCost = sharesInputed * company.PricePerShare;` ?   If it isn't in scope, it won't see the correct variable where the value is stored.

Comment: Also notice that `fRelative` is uninitialized when you pass it to `GetDlgItemInt`.  And have you looked at the value of `fError` after the call?  WinAPI functions do not give you "error messages" when they fail.

Comment: I haven't written that line yet because sharesinputed keeps returning 0.

Comment: In MSDN Documentation they do not initialize fRelative or fError? Either way, initializing them didn't make a difference.

Comment: You **probably** want `GetDlgItemInt(hwnd, IDC_EDITTYPESHARES, ...` (where `hwnd` is the parent dialog, not the edit control itself), but with an incomplete code fragment like this it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @DaBigBoy [I see none of what you are saying in the actual documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitemint).  If that last parameter is uninitialized, then your function is more than likely *not* going to behave correctly or behave erratically, depending on when, where, or how it is run.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: He's right, there is a [buggy example in the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modeless-dialog-box).

Comment: @DaBigBoy: Copy-pasting an example is not a good substitute for reading [the actual instructions associated with the function you are using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitemint).  According to that, if it fails it will return zero (what you're seeing) and set `fError` to `TRUE` (which you apparently aren't checking for) and set the last error (which you should read by calling `GetLastError()`)

Comment: Check out also [`ES_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-control-styles)

Answer (score 0):

Paul Sanders has correct answer. GetDlgItemInt wants the parent window. I was giving the window of my edit control instead, and now I'm getting the correct values.

Cheers!

Comment: Rather than creating a second answer to voice support for another answer, instead please vote or comment on that answer.